# Enforce link tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables, one called Season the other one Episode. Between them is a Link table that stores SeasonID and EpisodeID. How do I make sure that when a new episode is added the Link table will be updated as well?

Comment: mysql or sql-server ?

Comment: Can an episode belong to more than one season? If not, you have a one to many relationship instead of many-to-many and don't need the junction table. Just add SeasonID to the Episode table with a foreign key,

Comment: @scaisEdge sql-server I believe

Comment: @DanGuzman wow... I'm kicking myself now because this is actually exactly what I need... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using SQL Service.
We can achieve with the help of trigger like this

**Query**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_Update_Episode
ON [Episode]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM [dbo].[tblEpisodeSession] WITH (NOLOCK)
                 WHERE [EpisodeId] = [inserted.ID]) 
PRINT N'You must update an entry in tblSessionEpisode As well'; 

End
```

for both the table you should create a trigger like given above.

In example query you can replace message with your actual query which should actually create an entry in tblEpisodeSession.

Hope this helps.